# JavaFX - Getting the shape of a button based on background properties

Tags: javafx

As the title says, is there a way to get the shape of a button?
Because if I call the getShape() method, it returns null.
Furthermore if I style the button rounding its corners using the "-fx-background-radius" CSS selector, how can I get the shape with rounded corners?

PS: I'm working with jdk9 early access but I think this is a valid question also for jdk8.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you read the docs pertaining to `getShape` and `setShape`? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html#getShape-- The `Button` class inherits these two methods from the `Region` class.

Comment: I read and I understood, also checking inside Button.java source code, that there is no shape and the rendering seems that is based on the text label geometry of the button itself. Thus seems that there is no way to get a shape based on background.

Comment: Another fact I noticed is that I cannot get also the clip based on background. So how can I get the shape and the clip of a button (or whatever control) based on background radius and insets)? I bet there is a way but I'm not able to find it.

Answer (score 0):

As i not sure how rounded corner you meant so i provided some of the solution that work on my site

1. **-fx-background-radius**

you can use percentage to customize your button instead of value.

```
.cus_button {
-fx-background-radius: 50%;
}
```

2. **-fx-shape**

if you are using an **image view** to act as a button, you might need to use -fx-shape.

The string for fx-shape is the region path that you could get from a **.svg** format file. Otherwise, you could use a button and customize the shape will do.

[image: example format file]

```
.cus_button {
-fx-background-color: transparent;
-fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;
-fx-graphic: url("icons/btn_img.png"); 
-fx-shape:"M 0,0 5,-5 -12.5,0 5,5 0,0 z";}
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

A node has no clip unless you [set a clip](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setClip-javafx.scene.Node-).  Similarly, a region has no shape unless you [set a shape](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html#setShape-javafx.scene.shape.Shape-) in code or in CSS via `-fx-shape`.  Neither is done by default.  If the shape is defined in CSS, then it is necessary to [applyCSS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#applyCss--) before trying to retrieve the shape.

A background radius, which is part of a [background fill](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html#backgroundProperty), defines neither a [clip](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#clipProperty) nor [shape](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/Shape.html) (in the restricted way in which JavaFX uses these concepts).  So, if you are trying to work out the Shape for a background, you won't be able to, as they are different concepts which are not easily convertible.